# Company Name? Claim? New Column?

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am planning to use Identity Server 4 and Asp.net Core Identity together. My website that will be talking to Identity Server 4/Asp.net Core Identity will be expecting that a company name comes back with each user.

Should I create a new customer table called Company and in the Asp User table add a column linking them together.

Or should this be a claim?

I know when I authenticated my user and they are sent back to my main site, I  will have a company table and they will be linked but just not sure for the purposes of identifying them.

I feel like it should be a claim but I want to double check since I am new to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of using IdentityServer, technically *everything* is a claim. The "user" object IdentityServer returns will have all the properties mapped as claims. In that sense, it really doesn't matter which approach you go with.

However, it's generally better to keep data on your user table, if it makes sense to. Something like a foreign key relationship is especially valuable to exist at a database level, as there's more value to that than simply getting a company name.

Storing data as claims is most useful when that data is transient or not applicable to every user. Typical examples include things like third-party access tokens, such as from Facebook. Storing that on the database-level would inevitably result in denormalization of your database table, so it makes more sense to use a claim.

Comment: hmm, so you think both my Identity Server and then my website that consumes the data should both have company relationship between companies and users?